# ActionBar no muestra su contenido ni retorna ningún error o excepción, ¿Como lo arreglo?

Tags: c#, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android, actionbar

El título lo dice todo, no muestra la ActionBar mas ni tampoco ningún error o excepción

Estoy intentando centrar los componentes en sus posiciones, es decir, hacer que el objeto de la izquierda tenga la misma distancia relativa al muro izquierdo que el objeto de la derecha con respecto al muro de la derecha.

Puntos extra si me muestran como arreglarlo dejando ambas imágenes justo al lado de las murallas que les corresponden.

Así es como se ve hasta este punto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay que considerar que cambié completamente el código base (aunque guarde el código original), el motivo del cambio fue que no centraba los componentes como debía, pero ahora, no esta renderizando la ActionBar hecha por mi en absoluto, ni tampoco manda excepciones ni errores.

**¿Sabes que podría ser y como puedo logro lo que busco lograr?**

Aquí esta el código (el nuevo):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="750dp"
    android:minHeight="25dp"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_margin="2px"
        android:weightSum="4"
        android:minWidth="111dp">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_height="91dp"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/icon" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Gestión"
            android:layout_height="91dp"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center" 
            android:width="0px"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_height="91dp"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:background="@null"
            android:id="@+id/imgButtonLogOut"
            android:src="@drawable/primarylogout" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Desde ya, gracias por su atención

Comment: Podrías mostrar el código de tu activity?